# How to make excel return a date from a column corresponding to the last 'YES' in a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I'm trying to develop a spreadsheet tool to help track the training currencies of professional aircrew.  In order to be considered 'current' in all training, aviators must accomplish a variety of training events within set periods of time.

For instance, if a crew member has a 30-day currency for touch-and-go training, then he would want to know the date he must accomplish his next touch-and-go event before becoming non-current.

Considering the following spreadsheet of training events (1-5), dates, and YES/NO responses- is there a formula to return the most recent date for a given event?

```
          1   2   3   4   5
01/03/14|YES|NO |YES|NO |YES|
01/05/14|NO |NO |YES|YES|NO |
01/12/14|YES|YES|YES|YES|NO |
01/15/14|YES|NO |NO |NO |NO |
01/21/14|NO |NO |YES|YES|NO |
01/25/14|NO |YES|YES|NO |NO |
```

Given the pseudo table above, I'd like excel to return the following values:

For event 1: 01/15/2014
For event 2: 01/25/2014
For event 3: 01/25/2014
For event 4: 01/21/2014
For event 5: 01/03/2014

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  Type this in each training event column:

```
=MAX(IF(C3:C8="YES",$B$3:$B$8))
```

This is the formula that would apply for event 1. Assume that the dates are in column B and the event data starts from column C onwards.

This needs to be entered as an array formula so hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, combination of [max](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/max-function-HP010062517.aspx) and [if](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx), array formula

`=MAX(IF(B2:B7="YES",A2:A7))`

This is an array formula, you must hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> after typing it so curly brackets appear.

If it appears as a number, be sure to change the formatting back to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LOOKUP` which doesn't require "array entry". Assuming dates in column A

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:B7="Yes"),$A2:$A7)`

Note: this finds the last value "positionally" - assuming your dates are sorted in ascending order as per your example that will be the same as the last value chronologically